# Upper bound for the total curvature of a shortest path in the boundary of a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: differential-geometry, discrete-geometry, metric-geometry

Problem : Consider finitely many points in
$\mathbb{R}^3$. The boundary of the convex hull is $\Sigma$. When
$f_i$ is a face and $u_i$ is unit outnormal to $f_i$, then assume
that $$(-u_1)\cdot u_i >\eta>0 \ \ast$$ for all $i>1$ where $\cdot $ is an
inner product. When $P$ is a shortest path in $\Sigma -f_1$,

> then
> the total curvature of $P$ is smaller than $\frac{\pi}{\eta}$.

I need **another proof**, because the following well-known proof is not easy.

Proof : If $P$ contains line segments $[z_iz],\ [z z_{i+1}]$ in faces
$f_i, \ f_{i+1}$ where $z\in f_i\bigcap f_{i+1}$, then we define $$ x_i =\frac{z-z_i}{|z-z_i|},\
x_{i+1} = \frac{z_{i+1}-z}{|z_{i+1} -z|}$$

Similarly, we have any line segments $[\overline{z}_iz],\ [z
\overline{z}_{i+1}]$ in faces $f_i, \ f_{i+1}$ s.t. they are
orthogonal to $f_i\bigcap f_{i+1}$. Similarly we have
$\overline{x}_i,\ \overline{x}_{i+1}$. Then there is $$ x_i-x_{i+1}
= C_i (\overline{x}_i-\overline{x}_{i+1} )=\lambda_i( u_i + u_{i+1})
$$ where $C_i,\ \lambda_i>0$ : Here the second inequality is followed from drawing directly. If we set $x_i=A \overline{x}_i +B u_i\times \overline{x_i}$, then note that $x_{i+1}=A \overline{x}_{i+1} +B u_{i+1}\times \overline{x}_{i+1}$. Hence the first inequality is followed.

Hence $ -u_1\cdot( x_i-x_{i+1} ) \geq \lambda_i (2\eta ) $ Hence \begin{align*}
 \angle \
(x_i,x_{i+1}) &\leq \frac{\pi}{2}|x_i-x_{i+1}| \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} |\lambda_i (u_i+u_{i+1}) |
 \\&\leq \pi \lambda_i
 \\&\leq \pi\frac{-u_1\cdot (
 x_i-x_{i+1}) }{2\eta } \end{align*}

Hence $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \angle(x_i,x_{i+1}) \leq \frac{\pi}{2\eta} |u_1\cdot (x_1-x_n)| \leq \frac{\pi}{\eta}$.

Comment: What is the total curvature of a piecewise linear path? And I assume shortest paths are shortest rel endpoints?

Comment: Yes, total curvature is a sum of external angles between line segments. And yes. it is geodesic and minimizing (depends on end points)

Comment: I don't understand the proof you've given. At what point do you assume your path is length minimizing?

Comment: Consider the part of the curve in some face. Since it is minimizing so there is no external angle so that we do not consider. Further we consider the external angle around only edges (cf note that minimizing path does not pass through a vertex). Further since it is minimizing, then when we unfold it, then the path is straight line. Hence we consider the external angle in this case.

Comment: It sounds like you're only using the fact that the curve is *locally minimizing*. You can extend the geodesic along forever. At some point it stops being minimizing, so why is that related to how much curvature has been accumulated?

Comment: Yes we use the notion, locally minimizing only. And for the second question, I will edit (if I understand the point correctly).

Comment: I still don't see the point in your proof in which you've used the face that the curve is length minimizing between its endpoints. If you pick a point on $\Sigma$ and send a geodesic off in some direction, you can just let it go and go and increase its curvature almost endlessly as it rounds the corners. But it won't be a shortest path. How are you employing this in the proof?

Comment: It's not my proof. I just introduce. Sum of external angles from two faces is bounded from the quantity in terms of $x_1$ and $x_n$, even though it can turn arbitrarily large at some corner if it is possible.

Comment: This problem is to just find a necessary condition. Hence first part in the proof works for locally length minimizing. And second part works with $\ast$ for upper bound. That is, if $P$ is shortest, then we found the $least$ condition that $P$ satisfies. Yeah. if $P$ goes without stop, then total curvature goes to $\infty$. We do not know that it is possible. But in this problem with restriction $\ast$, at least we can conclude that total curvature can not go to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where $\Sigma$ is smooth Riemannian surface in
$\mathbb{R}^3$ of positive Gaussian curvature, homeomorphic to a
sphere. Define a region $D =\bigg\{ x\in \Sigma \bigg| N(x)\cdot v >\eta \bigg\}$
for some $|v|=1$ and $\eta>0$ where $N$ is unit out normal to
$\Sigma$.

Assume that $c:[0,l]\rightarrow D$ is a $\Sigma$-minimizing geodesic of unit
speed in $D$. Hence we have $|w(t)|=1,\ v\perp w(t)$ s.t. $$
N(t)=a(t)w(t) + b(t) v,\ b\geq \eta ,\ a^2+b^2=1$$

If $k$ is a curvature for $c$, then $c''(t)=-k(t)N(t),\ k>0$. Hence
\begin{align*} -c''\cdot v&=k b \geq k\eta \\
\int_0^l\ k(t)dt &\leq \int_0^l\ \frac{-c''\cdot v}{\eta} \ dt \\&=
-\frac{1}{\eta} c'(t)\cdot v \bigg|_0^l \\&\leq \frac{2}{\eta }
\end{align*}